# How to update the CLOB column with bulk data using sql oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, clob

I have the data like (7A+5dfAA7D...) alphabet and numbers.  Its length is greater than [two lack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh) characters.  So I can't update that clob column using `update` because it throws an error saying the string literal too long.

How to update the values?

please help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What sort of update are you doing: overwrsubiting? string replacement?  appending?

Comment: actually it is empty column simply update using simple update query

Comment: You will need to use a PreparedStatement (or whatever equivalent thing your programming language offers you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is part of some java code that inserts data from a file into a CLOB column. The trick is to first insert an empty_clob() value and then to update the record.

```
try {
            /* Register the Oracle driver */
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new OracleDriver());

            /* Establish a connection to the Oracle database. I have used the Oracle Thin driver.
              jdbc:oracle:thin@host:port:sid, "user name", "password" */

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectString, userName, passWord);

            /* Set auto commit to false, it helps to speed up things, by default JDBC's auto commit feature is on.
               This means that each SQL statement is commited as it is executed. */

            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            stmt = conn.createStatement();

            /* Insert all the data, for the BLOB column we use the function empty_blob(), which creates a locator for the BLOB datatype.
               A locator is an object that ponts to the actual location of the BLOB data in the database. A locator is essential to manipulate BLOB data. */

            query = "INSERT INTO CLOB_TABLE (id,data_clob,bestandsnaam,dt_geplaatst) " +
                    "VALUES(" + ID + ", empty_clob(),\'" + fileName + "\',sysdate)";

            //System.out.println(query);

            stmt.execute(query);

            /* Once the locator has been inserted, we retrieve the locator by executing a SELECT statement 
               with the FOR UPDATE clause to manually lock the row. */

            query = "SELECT DATA_CLOB FROM CLOB_TABLE WHERE ID=\'" + ID + "\' FOR UPDATE";

            //System.out.println(query);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            //System.out.println("Select statement uitgevoerd");

            if (rs.next()) {

                /* Once a locator has been retrieved we can use it to insert the binary data into the database. */
                CLOB clob = (CLOB)((OracleResultSet)rs).getClob(1);
                os = clob.getAsciiOutputStream();
                final File f = new File(fileName);
                is = new FileInputStream(f);
                final byte[] buffer = new byte[clob.getBufferSize()];
                int bytesRead = 0;
                while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                clob = null;
                returnValue = 0;
            }


        } catch
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL*Loader to load the data, but you have to do it from a file.  This may or may not be difficult depending on how much data is involved, though you could likely write a script which sets up sequential files containing your data.

For a table called TEST, with columns of TEST_ID and TEST_BLOB:

```
Control.dat:

load data
infile data.dat
replace 
into table TEST
Fields terminated by ','
(
  TEST_ID, 
   lob_file FILLER CHAR,
  TEST_CLOB LOBFILE(lob_file) TERMINATED BY EOF
)

data.dat:

1,c:\work\clob1_data.dat
2,c:\work\clob2_data.dat
etc...

C:\Work>sqlldr USER/PASS@dbserver.mycompany.com control=control.txt
sqlldr USER/PASS@dbserver.mycompany.com control=control.txt
SQL*Loader: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Thu Sep 24 01:20:06 2009
Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Commit point reached - logical record count 2
```

This configuration was derived from this example:  [Ask Tom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:627223659651)